# Use "devtool modify" to modify openbmc code

Tags: python, ubuntu, yocto, devtools, openbmc

I downloaded and tried to use devtool to get openbmc source code in ubuntu.

1.clone openbmc

```
git clone https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc
```

2.build image

```
export TEMPLATECONF=meta-ibm/meta-romulus/conf 
. openbmc-env
```

3.`bitbake obmc-phosphor-image`

4.build successful

5.try to get obmc-flash-bmc code

```
devtool modify obmc-flash-bmc
```

6.get error message

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'python' (but /xxxx/github-openbmc/meta-phosphor/recipes-phosphor/flash/obmc-flash-bmc_git.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it). Close matches:
  python3
  python3-py
  python3-sh
ERROR: Extracting source for obmc-flash-bmc failed
```

I have installed python3

```
python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `conf/bblayers.conf` file:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
    .../meta-openembedded/meta-python/
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but /meta-openembedded/meta-oe was already add in conf/bblayers.conf

Comment: sorry, I've meant `meta-python`, see edit

Comment: The meta-python was already add in conf/bblayers.conf too.
The following are my bblayers.conf:
`/openbmc/meta`
`/meta-openembedded/meta-oe`
`/meta-openembedded/meta-networking`
`/meta-openembedded/meta-perl`
`/meta-openembedded/meta-python`
`/meta-security`
`/meta-phosphor`
`/meta-aspeed`
`/meta-openpower`
`/meta-ibm/meta-romulus`
`/build/workspace`